# File download problem with php

Tags: php, download

I am having problem with file download script. I found a script in the following url-
http://www.tutorialchip.com/php-download-file-script/
This script is working nice in local(wamp server). But not working in server. It just goes to "download.php?f=Track_01_test.mp3". This is a blank page. I am using download path as -

```
$download_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."songs/main_songs/"
```

For download link, i am using -

```
<a href="download.php?f=2008_Track_02_We_Love_Bangladesh.mp3">Track-02-We Love Bangladesh.mp3</a>
```

Can anyone help me about this, Or suggest a better way/script? Thanks.

---

This is another script. This also works in local, but problem in server.

```
<?php

###############################################################
# File Download 1.31
###############################################################
# Visit http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/ for updates
###############################################################
# Sample call:
#    download.php?f=phptutorial.zip
#
# Sample call (browser will try to save with new file name):
#    download.php?f=phptutorial.zip&fc=php123tutorial.zip
###############################################################

// Allow direct file download (hotlinking)?
// Empty - allow hotlinking
// If set to nonempty value (Example: example.com) will only allow downloads when referrer contains this text
define('ALLOWED_REFERRER', '');

// Download folder, i.e. folder where you keep all files for download.
// MUST end with slash (i.e. "/" )
//echo ;
//example link - <a href="download.php?d=main_songs&f=2008_Track_02_We_Love_Bangladesh.mp3">Track-02-We Love Bangladesh.mp3</a>
define('BASE_DIR',$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/songs/'.$_REQUEST['d']);

// log downloads?  true/false
define('LOG_DOWNLOADS',true);

// log file name
define('LOG_FILE','downloads.log');

// Allowed extensions list in format 'extension' => 'mime type'
// If myme type is set to empty string then script will try to detect mime type 
// itself, which would only work if you have Mimetype or Fileinfo extensions
// installed on server.
$allowed_ext = array (

  // archives
  'zip' => 'application/zip',

  // documents
  'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
  'doc' => 'application/msword',
  'xls' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
  'ppt' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
  'html' => 'application/msaccess',
  'htm' => 'application/msaccess',

  // executables
  'exe' => 'application/octet-stream',

  // images
  'gif' => 'image/gif',
  'png' => 'image/png',
  'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
  'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',

  // audio
  'mp3' => 'audio/mpeg',
  'wav' => 'audio/x-wav',

  // video
  'mpeg' => 'video/mpeg',
  'mpg' => 'video/mpeg',
  'mpe' => 'video/mpeg',
  'mov' => 'video/quicktime',
  'avi' => 'video/x-msvideo'
);



####################################################################
###  DO NOT CHANGE BELOW
####################################################################

// If hotlinking not allowed then make hackers think there are some server problems
if (ALLOWED_REFERRER !== ''
&& (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) || strpos(strtoupper($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']),strtoupper(ALLOWED_REFERRER)) === false)
) {
  die("Internal server error. Please contact system administrator.");
}

// Make sure program execution doesn't time out
// Set maximum script execution time in seconds (0 means no limit)
set_time_limit(0);

if (!isset($_GET['f']) || empty($_GET['f'])) {
  die("Please specify file name for download.");
}

// Nullbyte hack fix
if (strpos($_GET['f'], "\0") !== FALSE) die('');

// Get real file name.
// Remove any path info to avoid hacking by adding relative path, etc.
$fname = basename($_GET['f']);

// Check if the file exists
// Check in subfolders too
function find_file ($dirname, $fname, &$file_path) {

  $dir = opendir($dirname);

  while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if (empty($file_path) && $file != '.' && $file != '..') {
      if (is_dir($dirname.'/'.$file)) {
        find_file($dirname.'/'.$file, $fname, $file_path);
      }
      else {
        if (file_exists($dirname.'/'.$fname)) {
          $file_path = $dirname.'/'.$fname;
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }

} // find_file

// get full file path (including subfolders)
$file_path = '';
find_file(BASE_DIR, $fname, $file_path);

if (!is_file($file_path)) {
  die("File does not exist. Make sure you specified correct file name."); 
}

// file size in bytes
$fsize = filesize($file_path); 

// file extension
$fext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fname,"."),1));

// check if allowed extension
if (!array_key_exists($fext, $allowed_ext)) {
  die("Not allowed file type."); 
}

// get mime type
if ($allowed_ext[$fext] == '') {
  $mtype = '';
  // mime type is not set, get from server settings
  if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
    $mtype = mime_content_type($file_path);
  }
  else if (function_exists('finfo_file')) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME); // return mime type
    $mtype = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
    finfo_close($finfo);  
  }
  if ($mtype == '') {
    $mtype = "application/force-download";
  }
}
else {
  // get mime type defined by admin
  $mtype = $allowed_ext[$fext];
}

// Browser will try to save file with this filename, regardless original filename.
// You can override it if needed.

if (!isset($_GET['fc']) || empty($_GET['fc'])) {
  $asfname = $fname;
}
else {
  // remove some bad chars
  $asfname = str_replace(array('"',"'",'\\','/'), '', $_GET['fc']);
  if ($asfname === '') $asfname = 'NoName';
}

// set headers
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: $mtype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$asfname\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . $fsize);

// download
// @readfile($file_path);
$file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
if ($file) {
  while(!feof($file)) {
    print(fread($file, 1024*8));
    flush();
    if (connection_status()!=0) {
      @fclose($file);
      die();
    }
  }
  @fclose($file);
}

// log downloads
if (!LOG_DOWNLOADS) die();

$f = @fopen(LOG_FILE, 'a+');
if ($f) {
  @fputs($f, date("m.d.Y g:ia")."  ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."  ".$fname."\n");
  @fclose($f);
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more code to help with the context of these (in case we're not familiar with that script) and a more detailed comparison of how it's working on the local server but not on another server?  As in, what are the key differences and where in the code are they happening?

Comment: Have you checked that php is allowed to open files in the specified directory on the server?

Comment: how can I check that? I have added some more codes to my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is abusing the [suppress errors operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) (`@`) and providing no alternative way to report errors so you are basically instructing the server to display a blank page when something fails. Furthermore, if you happen to have the [display_errors](http://es.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) directive set to `off`, PHP will just die silently if there is some other sort of problem.

My advice is:

<1> Enable full error reporting on top or your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
```

<2> Remove the `@` operator to be able to see error messages.

<3> Provide an alternative output if there are errors:

```
if ($f) {
   // ...
}else{ // <-- Add one of this
   // Do something if there's an error: print it on screen, log it...
}
```

Comment: I have done things according to your instruction and become little lucky. Some files are downloading. but maximum are not. Showing - "File does not exist. Make sure you specified correct file name." You can see my main site - http://celebratinglifebd.com/download-songs.php. Try to download some songs. 1st one downloads, but 2nd one does not. The file names I have provided, are correct. So I dont understand why it is showing File does not exist.

Comment: Most likely, because the file name is *not* correct. Be aware that Unix is case sensitive: `song.mp3` is different from `Song.mp3`.

Comment: Renamed the files to lowercase. I think this solved the problem. thanks a lot.